# How can I store just the TIME on MySQL with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

How can I store just the Time HH:MM:SS with sequelize?
I tried it with the Time as a String and also as a Date Object, but I always get an Error.
this is my function:

```
const dateCollection = await bookingTime.create({
            date: element.date,
            timeFrom: "12:00:00" || element.timeFrom,
            timeTo: element.timeTo
        })
```

The "12:00:00" is just for Test purpose.

And this is My Sequelize Model:

```
timeFrom: {
        type: DataTypes.TIME,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    timeTo: {
        type: DataTypes.TIME,
        allowNull: false,
    },
```

My Error:

```
"original": {
    "code": "ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE",
    "errno": 1292,
    "sqlState": "22007",
    "sqlMessage": "Incorrect date value: 'Invalid date' for column 'date' at row 1",
    "sql": "INSERT INTO `bookingTime` (`id`,`date`,`timeFrom`,`timeTo`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?);",
    "parameters": [
        "Invalid date",
        "12:00:00",
        "13:00:00"
    ]
},
```

DDL:

```
 CREATE TABLE `bookingTime` (
  `id` int(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeFrom` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeTo` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `bookingID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `machineID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKmachineBT_idx` (`machineID`),
  KEY `FKbookingBT_idx` (`bookingID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKbookingBT` FOREIGN KEY (`bookingID`) REFERENCES `booking` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FKmachineBT` FOREIGN KEY (`machineID`) REFERENCES `machine` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

Thanks in advance for any Answers

Comment: Please provide the error what you got

Comment: I have provided it right now thanks

Comment: Fine! Also your 'booking Time ' table structure will be much appreciate. Looks as you created table with date type column instead time. Look MySQL date & time types here:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: Thanks I hope this will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding set Methods to the Model. I don't know why it works now, but it does.

```
date: {
        type: DataTypes.DATEONLY(),
        allowNull: false,
        set (valueToBeSet) { 
            this.setDataValue('date', valueToBeSet)
        }
    },
    timeFrom: {
        type: DataTypes.TIME,
        allowNull: false,
        set (valueToBeSet) { 
            this.setDataValue('timeFrom', valueToBeSet)
        }
    },
    timeTo: {
        type: DataTypes.TIME,
        allowNull: false,
        set (valueToBeSet) { 
            this.setDataValue('timeTo', valueToBeSet)
        }
    },
```

Comment: Reference here: [Sequelize Setters](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/getters-setters-virtuals/#setters)

Comment: For me worked with something like this:
`this.setDataValue('timeFrom', this.sequelize.fn('SEC_TO_TIME', valueToBeSet))` instead of `this.setDataValue('timeFrom', valueToBeSet)
`